# POST method Error HTTP 405 (Method not allowed)

Tags: web-services, rest, jsp, servlets, post

I am building a simple web app and attempting to insert data into a database using servlets and RESTful web services and I am getting this error HTTP 405 (Method not allowed). Can you please give me some suggestions?

This code is from the web services.

```
@POST
    @Path("/2")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public boolean addBooks(@FormParam("id") int id, @FormParam("isbn") 
String isbn, @FormParam("title") String title, @FormParam("author") String 
author, @FormParam("genre") String genre, @FormParam("availability") Boolean 
availability, @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
            throws IOException {
      boolean result = DBManager.getInstance().addBook(id, isbn, title, author, genre, availability);
      return result;
    }
```

This code is from the servlet.

```
WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());
Boolean ok = target.path("rest").path("hello/2").request()
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(Boolean.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending the server a GET request instead of a POST.

Try:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams = new MultivaluedHashMap();
formParams.put("title", ...);
formParams.put("isbn", ...);
...
Boolean ok = target.path("rest").
                    path("hello/2").
                    request().
                    accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).
                    post(Entity.form(formParams), Boolean.class);
```

Comment: I tried this, but this error appeares: The method post(Entity<?>) in the type SyncInvoker is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Boolean>)

Comment: Well, we both forgot the form parameters didn't we?